# Android Fused Location Api

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am using Fused Location Api for getting the latitude and longitude.It's mentioned in the documents that it uses GPS,Wifi and network to return the most accurate location of the user.I want to ask is that will it return the position if the  GPS in my phone is switched off?

Comment: Maybe wifi or mobile data, if on

Answer (score 0):

Fused Location Provider will automatically choose the best location from the options available.  It will select from GPS or Network location Provider.  So if the device GPS is not on, you should still be able to get a location based on the network location provider, if that is enabled on the device.

You will need to have permissions for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION to receive both kinds of locations.